# Edit and upload Game Center achievements and leaderboard using Application Loader

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center

Since it's possible to download Game Center metadata through Transporter into a .itmsp package file, how would you edit and upload that file using Application Loader? I see no interface for Game Center metadata in Application Loader. Application Loader is default app to open .itmsp packages. Did I miss something?
At <s>worst</s> best I guess it could be possible to edit the contained .xml file, add a few achievements, and then try to upload that into iTunes Connect using Application Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a lookup on an existing app inside your `Itunes` account, you download a file called like like the vendor_id with the .itmsp format. My experience was, opening this file by double clicking inside the `Application Loader`just changes the data inside this archive.

In my case, an additional file was created called something like `meta-local...` and the `metadata.xml` from `Itunes Connect` has been changed. It's like the `Application Loader` deletes information like description, keywords, url`s, screenshots and all the data you have to define the first time you create the app before uploading the binary.

Instead of using the `Application Loader` you should open the .itmsp file by right clicking and selecting `show package content`. This way nothing will be changed and you can open the metadata and change specific data.

I don't have `Game Center` elements included in my app yet but I did some researches on tools which could automate the process of generating and changing data. Have a look at these projects, the first one looks like it could be exactly what you're looking for:

[iTunes Transporter Generator](https://github.com/colinhumber/itunes_transporter_generator)
[iTunes Store Connector](https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter)
[iTunes Store Transporter Web](https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter_web)

If not maybe you could create an `Apple Script` to parse the metadata.xml and add or change your data.
I would appreciate if you could leave a comment if any of these tools could help you with the `Game Center` problem.